# Video.js was not injected in your file

Tags: html, bower, video.js

So I'm trying out video.js as I need to create a video player with a playlist. I've little to none experience with this so excuse me if this a dumb question but this is the message I'm getting.

> video.js was not injected in your file.
>   Please go take a look in "C:\Path\bower_components\video.js" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

What do I need to manually include? 
To originally use video.js I used to the following command.

> bower install --save video.js

Comment: Have you added the js file to your html?

Comment: @Sirence Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: You need to tell your html page where it can find the video.js file after you installed it with bower. See this for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: @Sirence does it matter what html file? Because I have tried that at the top of the page that I want the videos to be in but still getting the same error

Comment: It needs to be put in the page where you want to use the video. Usually it is put in either the head tag, or within the body tag before the `</body>` line, see this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp. The path needs be set relative to where the html file is. You can add the code of the html page where you added it to your question, then we can take a look at the include.

Answer (score 0):

Try  as this example

```js
      videojs('my_video_1', {
        plugins: {
          loopbutton: true 
        }
      }, function () {
        // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
      });
```

```html
 

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268"  
data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],"loopbutton": true  }'
>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

Comment: The comes up but the default media player. Just to be 100% sure where does the js go?

Comment: Do you mean video js??. If it is then i have edited above code placing it. For futher information you can visit https://videojs.com/getting-started/

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I have <script src="path/video.js"> in my code but it still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: "path" is the name of the folder the video.js file is in?

Comment: @Sirence well no "C:\WebDev/DonsManager/client/client/bower_components/video.js/src/js/video.js" is the exact path but that's not really 100% necessary.

Comment: No, you only have to add the path relativlely from the html. Which is the path you have added to your html file?

Comment: @Sirence <script src="../../bower_components/video.js/src/js/video.js"></script> is exactly what I have. My html page in a folder called help which is in a folder called views. Views and bower_components are on the same level then. I appreciate this help by the way thank you

Comment: The path looks correct - in which part of your html page did you put this? The header?

Comment: @Sirence I tried it in the header but it's currently in the div where I want the videos to be. See I'm also working off someone else's work who I cannot contact for the next few days as they're away so not sure if they have something set up for injecting bower components.

Comment: You can try to put it below the videos, to make sure the videos exists in the page when the script is loaded. Apart from that I am all out of ideas sadly. Maybe there is a different component on another page that you could use as a reference for how your colleague does it?

Comment: @Sirence Tried below the videos too, the video definitely exists because it's loading but just using the default media player. Ya I've been looking for something similar but it's a fairly big project so hard to find. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: For the existing, this is regarding how the elements are loaded - if the script gets loaded before the videos are loaded, it will say it can not find them. It will not look again, even if your videos will be there on the page later on. Your videos might not exist when the js file is loaded. See this reference: https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/